# ng-include not working for basic angular 1 code

Tags: angularjs

Ok, there're many similar questions, i went through some and get me more confused, btw i started learning angular 1 about 2 weeks ago.

1. in browser, /mypath/status.html works fine, it sends "testJson" to node server, then 
   displays data to the webpage
2. now i have /mypath/index2.html, which ng-include status.html, it won't 
   trigger "testJson" in the server code

status.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="HelloModule">
  <head>
      <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  </head>

  <body  ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/
angular.js"></script>
    <script src="statusApp.js"></script>


    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Population</th>
      </tr>


      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries | orderBy: 'code' ">
        <th>{{country.code}}</th>
        <th>{{country.name}}</th>
        <th>{{country.population}}</th>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

statusApp.js

```
var app = angular.module('HelloModule', []);

app.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, HelloService) {
        //$scope.countries = [{code : "US", name : "United States", population : "11223344"}];

    HelloService.getJson().then(function(result) {
        $scope.countries = result;
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Error");
    } );
});


app.factory('HelloService', function($http, $q) {

  return {
     getJson:  function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var browserProtocol = 'http';
        var port = ':1234';
        var address = 'localhost';
        var server = browserProtocol + '://' + address;
        var url = server + port + '/testJson';

        //$http.get('http://localhost:7778/testJson').success(function(data) {
        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(){
            deferred.reject();
        }); 

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

index2.html which is not working,
i don't see this line
     console.log("returning Json data");
triggered in the server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
   <head>
       <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
   </head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.
min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div ng-include="" src="'status.html'"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

server side

```
app.get('/testJson', function(req, res)
{
        console.log("returning Json data");
    res.json( [{code : "US", name : "United States", population : "11223344"
}] );
});
```

Comment: there are a couple things wrong here.  First, `ng-include` is intended to include code snippets, not full pages.  second, you are correct, it will not trigger the JavaScript on the included snippet, by design.  Also, a blank `ng-app` will not function properly in the version of angular that you are using, that's a depreciated syntax.

Comment: so many versions, do you happen to have a good example pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status.html that you want to include is :

```
  <table ng-controller="HelloCtrl" >
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Population</th>
      </tr>


      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries | orderBy: 'code' ">
        <th>{{country.code}}</th>
        <th>{{country.name}}</th>
        <th>{{country.population}}</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Right ?

***EDIT***

And **ng-include** works like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-include="'status.html'" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, status.html can get this country json object from server and display properly, but when i include status.html into index2.html, the later one is not working. Server seems never hit "/testJson"

Comment: you suggest to put ng-controller="HelloCtrl" in the <table> ? tried that, still not working

Comment: Where did you put this script ? <script src="statusApp.js"></script>

Comment: all these files are under .../client, except the node server code is under .../server

Comment: "Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/ng/areq?p0=HelloCtrl&p1=not%20a                 nanunction%2C%20got%20undefined
I/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js:6:409
qb@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js:22:125
Sa@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js:22:304
Ve/this.$get</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js:80:81

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="HelloModule">
   <head>
       <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
   </head>

<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="statusApp.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div ng-include="'status.html'"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>

Comment: Perfect ! It's why I asked you Where did you put this script ? <script src="statusApp.js"></script>.